# Error while executing raw sql query in django

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-views

**I am trying to use raw query in django view :**

[image]

**but it is showing error:**

[image]

**database table named auth_user:**

[image]

**my point is:  'where' clause should check for column named "username" why it checking for column "chaitanya360" which is obviously not present in table.**

Comment: Literal strings are enclosed in single quotes, double quotes are used for identifiers (that's why it assumed you meant a column)

Comment: right! I tried using double quotes. can you please tell me why is so difference is there.